# Codeigniter with Doctrine for large application

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, doctrine

I am about to start a project on PHP and selected Codeigniter as a framework to be used after receiving lot of plus comments from Codeigniter-users ;-)

I am not much clear about which ORM to be used with codeigniter. I was advised to use Doctrine. Is there any tool available for codeigniter to create models and db mapping with Doctrine on command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Doctrine itself for creating models. Follow the cookbook

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/cookbook/code-igniter-and-doctrine/en

to setup, so then in /application/ you can use

$ ./doctrine [command]

to create models and mappings.

Note: in this moment I'm failing to access any page at the doctrine-project.org site. May be later...

Comment: Hi Mora,
Thanks for the reply. I was about to use Doctrine 2.0, which is said the latest stable release. But I the problem I got here is it worked only on php 5.3 and above. Most of the servers we are working on is with php 5.2 and will not be updated to php 5.3 sooner. So what is your suggestion? Is that ok to use Doctrine 1.2 with Codeigniter 2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using 1.2 with CI 1.7.3 and works painless. Doctrine 2.0 was a serious rewrite, but it doesn't means that 1.2 is buggy, so I recommend it.